# Does Data Import Replace Existing Data in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: database, mysql-workbench

I'm working with a database in a development environment in MySQL Workbench. I have everything ready to go and need to move it to a prod database. I've exported it to a sql file but I'm unsure if I'm approaching the import the correct way.

If I use the "Data Import/Restore" feature, select my SQL file, and import, will it replace the existing data in the database (what I want to happen) or will it add new records to each table for the new data?

The schema is the same in each database. I just need to replace the old data in the prod database with the new data from dev.

Thanks for your help

Comment: You can easily control that yourself. Just drop the schema you are going to import. Then you are 100% sure.

Answer (score 4):

That depends on how your export-file looks. Just open it in a text editor and read over the statements in your export-file.

By default it should contain statements like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customer` (
  `CUSTOMER_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CUSTOMER_NM` varchar(100) DEFAULT ''
) EN
```

and right after it the data of this table:

```
INSERT INTO `customer` (`CUSTOMER_ID`, `CUSTOMER_NM`) VALUES
(0, 'Dummy Customer');
(1, 'Dummy Two');
```

Since your tables already exist in your PROD-Environment it will not delete, create or replace them (Note the `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`-Statement). The `INSERT`-Stamement will be executed (there is no condition which says it shouldn't).

So after importing your file you will have your previous PROD-Data in your database + the imported DEV-Data your your DEV-Environment.

On the other hand it could contain a statement like:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `customer`
```

And right after it the `CREATE`-Statement followed by some `INSERT`-Statements. In this case your whole `PROD`-Database will be replaced by the DEV-Database as you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL specific `replace` statement to achieve this goal. [check out this link](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-replace.aspx)